# Recorrido por anchura arbol binario C#

Tags: c#, .net, consola, árboles-binarios

Tengo un arbol binario con los siguientes codigos

```
namespace Arboles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinarySearchTree nums = new BinarySearchTree();
            nums.Insert(23);
            nums.Insert(45);
            nums.Insert(16);
            nums.Insert(37);
            nums.Insert(3);
            nums.Insert(99);
            nums.Insert(22);
            Console.WriteLine("Recorrido Posorder: ");
            nums.InOrder(nums.root);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es hacer recorrido por anchura, ya intente de todo pero no me sale
Intente hacer con un while e ir guradando el nodo anterior para despues regresar pero nada
Mi arbol tiene los metodos de InOrder, PosOrder, pero yo necesito listarlos por anchura

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de tu clase arbol, para saber que metodos se pueden usar

Comment: Hola, resolviste?

Comment: Si lo pude resolver

Comment: Hiram seria bueno que compartieras tu solución con la comunidad y explicaras el código

Comment: Aqui mismo? o en otra publicacion?

Comment: En tu publicación abajo debe haber un espacio para q le des respuesta a tu propia pregunta

Comment: O siii, buscare el codigo y le hago una explicacion y lo subo